# Best practice for keeping JS at bottom of page using componentized modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I am looking for best practices/design patterns for keeping JavaScript in external JS files/bottom of the page. I am running into a problem where my pages are built from a number of components, and each component replies on a jquery component that needs several params passed to it.

So for instance in a JSP

```
<div class="component-a">
   <div id="js-slideshow-<%= slide-id %>" class="js-slideshow"></div>
</div>
<script>$('#js-slideshow-<%= slide-id %>').initslideshow({'path':<%= path %>});</script>
```

The problem is I now have  tags peppering my markup and there is alot of repeat code. Ideally I would break out all these JS calls into a JS file that is included at the bottom of the page.

My initial thought would be to load up any params the jquery plugins need as data-* attributes.

Something like

JSP

```
<div class="component-a">
   <div data-path="<%= path %>" class="js-slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

JS file

```
<script>
$(".js-slideshow").each(function() { 
   $(this).initslideshow('path': $(this).attr('data-path'));
});
</script>
```

Are there any other good patterns for keeping JavaScript separated out in JS files even when the calls require data/context the server needs to provide and may only be available from the context of a component?

---

**Clarifications:**

This is simply practice of breaking out common presentation elements into separate files. Ruby on Rails partials are one example of this. 
One component may be a "Slideshow" but depending on which page its located on i may want adjust its behavior using different values, such as different sets of images to show, different size images, or a different title, etc. This "variety" in parameters "known" by the server, and it would be up to the server to understand the context to pull the param values from a serverside data store and write them to the JS calls.

Ideally I would like to minimize the number of times the same "base" JS is written out and execute it at the bottom once for the following reasons:
1. Decrease page weight
2. Increase readability of generated HTML
3. Moved javascript code (even if they are just calls) from the HTML file to a JS file(s) - which is a clean separation of code and data
4. Allows for more data to be cached (the JS file can be cached and the extra page weight doesnt have to be downloaded on other page requests)
5. Avoid the scenario of more complex components having multiple events bound to the same element. For example:

`$(".slideshow").init('<%= param %>')` adds a bind event to the `.slideshow` element, if I call `$(".slideshow").init('<%= param %>')`  multiple times, multiple events will be bound to that DOM element. (I think bind works like that, if not live or delegate does).
I can get around it by calling `init` on a uniquely named element, but this requires adding unique ids to each slideshow DOM element, which seems unnecessary.

In terms of development I will most likely have a separate JS file for each component, but will pack them into a single file during the build process.

Comment: What problem is it causing? Putting the script element directly below the element it relates to is quite efficient. You can add parameter values in the *class* or *data-* attributes, then have a single script make calls using the class/data- values as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what you are saying is that the parts of your site come in "modules" that have their own HTML and JS, and that when you sum it all up, they are just in the middle of things?

i suggest you put script paths as variables or `data-*` and have a loader at the bottom do the lazy loading later.

like say:

```
<div class="component" data-source="path_to_script">
    your module HTML
```

then at the bottom of your page, before your `, you have some script that does:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        //loader script
        (function loader(){

            //loop through all components
            $('.component').each(function(){

                //get the path and load script
                var scriptUrl = $(this).data('source');
                $.getScript(scriptUrl);

                //or if params
                var params = $(this).data('params'); //may be in JSON string perhaps?
                //parse JSON here
                $(this).initSlideshow(params);                    

            });
        }());
    });
</script>
```

in the end, you have a clean page. at least, you need jQuery and the code above in the page. the rest of your scripts are dynamically loaded at the bottom.

Comment: Which requires the OP to have a separate script file for each "component" and may be very inefficient by making lots of requests. Far better to have a single script file and call functions using the parameters.

Comment: @RobG he does say *"where my pages are built from a number of components"* so i assumed that each part was built by someone else or must be separately built.

Comment: Which means if the script relevant to each component is in the component, it's already pretty efficient and nicely coupled to the part of the page it belongs to. I can't see why the OP wants to modify the design to meet some "best practice" idiom that likely isn't suitable (measured by relevant, practical criteria) in this case.

Comment: @RobG page load times i guess? maybe he wants to load and parse scripts last. you know, UI and styles first, behaviors later kinda thing.

Comment: @Robg - I agree having separate JS files would be too http request intense. I am packing my JS during build process.

Comment: @Joseph It seems like youre going down the path of attaching component-instance specific JS params as data-* and pulling them out in the JS function? My question was more around getting params that are known to the server into the JS function invocations, rather than how to load the JS files.

Comment: @Robg - I added clarifications for my reasons why i dont want JS snippets to be at the bottom of each component. there is also the use case where SlideShowA and SlideShowB components use the same JS, but render different markup. Extracting the JS would allow the everything to be contained in a single place (the JS file) rather than in Component JSPs which are really responsible for rendering HTML. Can you think of any downsides of writing JS params as data-* values? I can't.

Comment: The only down side is that some browsers do not convert non-standard attributes to DOM properties, so you must access them with *getAttribute* for reliability. However, don't use *getAttribute* in general though because it's broken in IE for some uses. As long as you only use it for data- attributes you should be fine. For everything else, just read the DOM property directly.